# Update character kills and deaths with resultset

Tags: mysql

I tryed to find an answer for this based on other questions, but I couldn't implement the logic into my necessity.

I can easily get the informations I need, however I can't update a table with those informations.

I have selected all the necessary values using the following query:

```
select `roleid`, 
(select count(`killerid`) from `kills` where `killerid`=`roleid`) as `kills`, 
(select count(`corpseid`) from `kills` where `corpseid`=`roleid`) as `deaths` 
from `characters`
```

So this query returns the character's ID with its respective kills and deaths number.

Now, I need to know: How can I update table "characters", setting rows "kills" and "deaths" to the returned values in the query?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: you want to get the kill amount and death amount, then put it back into the database? Are you going to change the amount before updating? What are you using? MYSQLI? PDO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE characters c 
  LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT killerid, count(*) as kill_num FROM kills GROUP BY killerid ) k1
  ON c.roleid = k1.killerID 
  LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT corpseid, count(*) as death_num FROM kills GROUP BY corpseid ) k2
  ON c.roleid = k2.corpseID
SET c.kills = k1.kill_num, c.deaths = k2.death_num
```

Comment: VERY good. Thank you so much sir. It's the first time I use this website, and I'm still learning database programming. Due to this, I can't "thumb up" - or whatever it is in this website - your answer.

 I noticed something: first time I used the query, all characters were updated, but the second run (made some 10 seconds after xD) has updated 0 rows. So I'm guessing it doesn't change equal rows. Is that correct?

Comment: It shows number of rows that were actually changed. With no changes to the kills table no changes were made after running the same update again.